# Riemann-integrability - function with countable-many discontuities and function with countable-many alterations

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I am confused regarding Riemann-integrability of functions with countable-many discontinuities.

Let's say we have one Riemann-integrable function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ with countably-infinite-many discontinuities and another function $g:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous (and hence Riemann-integrable).

Now suppose that we change successively countably-infinite-many points of $g$ such that $g$ becomes discontinuous at those points.

1.) I am wondering if the following two thoughts on proving the Riemann-integrability are correct:

-I can show the Riemann-integrability of $g$ via induction.

-Proving Riemann-integrability of $f$ via induction is not possible.

2.) If the Riemann-integrability of $f$ can't be proven by induction, why is that so?

Comment: Well, induction is a finite concept. If the number of discontinuities tends to infinity, this might destroy everything. So I don't think that induction is a valid argument.

Comment: @Shaqinho, ah ok I think I have misunderstood something regarding induction. If I prove a statement $S(n)$ via induction then it is true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. However, I am not allowed to "plug in" $\infty$ and evaluate $S(\infty)$? Right?

Comment: That is correct, yes.